# Break peak inrush current

Tags: emi-filtering, inrush-current

I want to renew a 30 Year old line-filter 230V AC for an electronic device. At the end of the filter is a 230V transformer with 9 secondary outlets: 5.8V, 51.4V, 16V, 13.3V, 9V, 9.8V, 18V, 80V, 100V. They power circuit boards with CPU, IC's and more. I don't have the inductivity of this transformer.

1. Do the thermistor and varistor protect the transformer or only the switch and fuse?
2. Is it recommended here to use a Soft Start Circuit Power Board to protect transformer and circuit boards?
3. Can I use a normal line-filter without thermistor and varistor? Just coils and capacitors?

The filter looks like this:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

> Do the thermistor and varistor protect the transformer or only the switch and fuse?

Varistor should be placed to protect the entire product against over voltages, surges, lightning strikes etc. NTC thermistor is a form of inrush limiting: Its resistance is high at cold, so when the product is first energised and the input caps are empty, lower currents will flow. As the product runs the input current flows through that thermistor. So its temperature will increase thus its resistance will decrease, and so does its dissipation.

> Is it recommended here to use a Soft Start Circuit Power Board to protect transformer and circuit boards?

Soft start circuit is doesn't protect the transformer.

> Can I use a normal line-filter without thermistor and varistor? Just coils and capacitors?

I don't know what the left-most capacitor's value is. When the power is first applied, a high current will flow through it first. The DC resistance of the filter inductance may help for the rest of the circuit but for the left-most capacitance, a high inrush current is still a thing to consider.

Remember that varistor (MOV or VDR) does nothing to help to decrease the inrush current.

Comment: But as I understand in the diagram, this is a PTC thermistor (.º+) It has no resistant on cold and builds up on hot. Should't it be the opposite, a NTC (.º-) thermistor? I think there is no inrush limiter here. This thermistor protects the device if there is to much power drawn, it gets hot and limits the current. Or maybe it gets hot so quickthatitlimits the power. on. rush?

Comment: @Atalantia `Should't it be the opposite, a NTC (.º-) thermistor?` Maybe the designer didn't care about the symbols and conventions. `This thermistor protects the device if there is to much power drawn, it gets hot and limits the current.` This job should have been shouldered by the fuse, actually. And also, the fuse supposed to protect the varistor. But looking at the fuse, it's "timed", not "fast acting". Strange.